# ¿Qué tipo de oración es "nunca se hubiera imaginado"?

Tags: sintaxis

> También ella lo había visto muchas veces, y nunca se hubiera imaginado
>   que estuviera allí sólo para verla.

Que yo sepa, *que estuviera allí sólo para verla* es una oración complementaria ¿verdad?

Pero ¿qué tipo de oración es *nunca se hubiera imaginado*?

Comment: Personalmente tengo muy oxidada la morfología, pero diría que ahí tienes dos frases y la segunda empieza en el "y". Efectivamente el "que" inicia una frase complementaria pero es necesaria para la parte del "y", sino esta no tendría sentido alguno.

Comment: No me queda claro por qué divides a las oraciones en fragmentos. Las oraciones se analizan completas, hasta el punto.

Comment: Matías, estoy de acuerdo! Mira, es q tengo q explicar el uso del subjuntivo en esta frase. En la oración complementaria se usa „estuviera“ después del verbo cognitivo (imaginar) que lleva la frase precedente. pero ¿qué hago con „nunca se hubiera imaginado “? ¿cómo lo explico?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que nada, desde mi perspectiva hay un error en la formación del verbo (aunque esto es discutible). Debería usarse el condicional **habría** en lugar del pretérito imperfecto subjuntivo **hubiera**. Con ese cambio, el análisis gamátical es más o menos así:

Hay dos oraciones proposicionales coordinadas por la conjunción **y**.

> 1. *también ella lo había visto muchas veces*

El sujeto es *"ella"*. El predicado es *"también lo había visto muchas veces"*. Muy simple, no requiere mayor análisis.

> 2. [ella] nunca se habría imaginado que estuviera allí sólo para verla

Esta oración es más complicada. El sujeto "ella" se elide porque está en oración anterior. El predicado es así:

2.1 Núcleo: el verbo **habría imaginado** (condicional perfecto).

2.2 Adyacentes:

2.2.1 Adverbio **nunca**, que acota la circunstancia temporal del verbo (en realidad de todo el predicado).

2.2.2 Morfema pronominal **se**, sin función sintáctica.

2.2.3 Complemento directo **que estuviera allí sólo para verla**. Es el objeto del verbo, *lo nunca imaginado*.

El complemento directo corresponde, como te das cuenta, a una oración que está subordinada al verbo principal por medio del pronombre **que**.

> 2.2.3 [él] estuviera allí solo para verla

No manejo el concepto "oración complementaria", pero creo que estamos de acuerdo en que es una construcción sintáctica secundaria que "apoya" a una oración principal. El verbo está conjugado en subjuntivo: "estuviera", como ocurre siempre en las oraciones subordinadas. *Supongo* que se llama "complementaria" porque sirve de *complemento* directo.

En resumen, para responder tu pregunta, *nunca se hubiera imaginado* no es una oración correcta en este caso. El verbo está en subjuntivo, por lo que requiere obligatoriamente ir encabezada por un conector que la subordine (principalmente un **que** o un **si**). Como este conector no existe, debería ser *nunca se habría imaginado*, la cual no tiene nada de especial, es simplemente una oración proposicional simple y principal.